# Connection Mysql Workbench Vagrant

Tags: mysql, ssh

I'm using OSX and I have problem to connect MySQL workbench to my vagrant.

I have this configuration:

[image: config]

the vagrant password is vagrant and the mysql password is root

And I have this error

[image: error]

I don't know really if the error is on the mysql connection or ssh connection

`ssh vagrant@33.33.33.15` works

I have an error when MySQL workbench is connecting to ssh

```
14:58:42 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
14:58:42 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to 33.33.33.15
14:58:42 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:233]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/sshtunnel.py", line 257, in _connect_ssh
    self._client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(ssh_known_hosts_file))
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/paramiko/client.py", line 176, in load_host_keys
    self._host_keys.load(filename)
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 155, in load
    e = HostKeyEntry.from_line(line)
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/libraries/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 67, in from_line
    key = RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring(key))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 321, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
Error: Incorrect padding

14:58:42 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: TunnelManager.wait_connection returned OK
14:58:42 [INF][sshtunnel.py:set_keepalive:471]: SSH KeepAlive setting skipped.
14:58:42 [INF][     SSH tunnel]: SSH tunnel connect executed OK
```

I already try to edit my.cnf on my vagrant commenting bind-address or setting bind-address to 0.0.0.0 but I have the same problem.

Edit: I have the same error on a real server

Comment: are you using a valid ssh port number in your connectivity?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure port 22 works

Comment: Change the MySQL Hostname to 33.33.33.15

Comment: @harunyardimci I have the same error

Comment: And can you try to change SSH Hostname to 127.0.0.1:22

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue today and tracked it down to being an offensive entry in my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

A way to troubleshoot this is by moving ~/.ssh/known_hosts to ~/.ssh/known_hosts_test and then trying your connection in MySQL Workbench again.

I found that a recent host I connected to left me with a known_hosts entry that MySQL workbench didn't like.  The error message in the logs was the same as yours, and simply killing the last couple of entries in known_hosts fixed the issue for me.

Cheers!

Comment: This may also be an issue due to having multiple vagrant instances and their SSH Keys being stored as 'localhost' and not matching up when connecting between instances.  Just a thought.

Comment: This is exactly my problem (multiple instances) -- is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to an incompatibility in the underlying `paramiko` python lib, that doesn't support newer key exchange methods (i.e. ECDH) of your server...

Unfortunately until today, the MySQL-dev didn't upgrade their lib.

A possible workaround would be to create the ssh tunnel yourself:

`ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 vagrant@33.33.33.15`

And then connect directly via MySQL-Workbench to `localhost:3306`.

Comment: MySQL Workbench 6.3.7 seems to support newer ciphers. In my case, it works well.